# Is it possible to replace the Unity launcher?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, dock

Is it possible to replace the Unity launcher (dock) in Ubuntu 11.04 with another dock (for example Docky)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will certainly be possible to continue with whatever setup you use now. (Not use Unity, but a different dock.)

However whether it will be possible to use the rest of the Unity interface alongside a different dock remains to be seen. With current Unity (10.10) that is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

In Unity 10.10 it's possible to use Docky, obviously not on the left, and Unity dock is not removable, so you have both on the screen. You can't replace but you can use another dock alongside the original one.

Unity + Docky

[image]

Comment: Just to say - seeing as Unity in 11.04 will have autohide this is more of a feasible option than before.

Comment: In 11.04 you can hide the launcher permanently but as stated there is currently no way to remove it.

Comment: You _CAN_ stop the launcher from starting at all. You just won't be able to use lenses and all the other launcher goodies.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible by replacing the launcher component:

For unity 2d:

Open nautilus in root and navigate to /usr/bin,
Rename unity-2d-launcher to unity-2d-launcher2 and copy and rename for example docky to unity-2d-launcher.

for unity: not possible...

It is possible for unity2d but not recommended...