# Will the Unity Launcher be removable?

Tags: unity, 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to replace the unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9967/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-unity-launcher)

I happen to like Docky; I also like AWN and other such docks. 
So my question is, with Ubuntu 11.04, and Unity; can I still keep 'Unity' but operate without the Dock? (or indeed, other elements?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes I believe so. So far it has been as simple as

```
sudo aptitude search unity #Remove all packages
sudo aptitude search netbook #This was done for netbook editions
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

There is no reason that a similar process for unity desktop won't carry over.

Comment: I think Dante Ashton is asking if it will be possible to use the Unity interface without the unity dock. If not, this question is a duplicate of [several others](http://askubuntu.com/q/10765/667).